# Jquery on dynamically loaded div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have following code,

html form

```
<form id="t-files">
    <a style="margin-left:160px;" class="list-directories" href="#">Select File Path</a><br><br>
    <div id="fileList"></div>
</form><br>
```

Ajax code to get folder names

```
 $('.folderLink').on('click', function (e) { 
    alert('hello');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'list-directories-inner.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: $('#t-files').serialize(),
        success: function (data) { 
            alert(data);
            //$("#fileList").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

php file to handle folder names

```
<?php        
    $path    = 'templates';
    $files = scandir($path);

    foreach($files as $result) {
         if ($result != "." && $result != ".." && $result != "desktop.ini")
            {
                  echo '<img src="img/folder.png" width="40px"><a name="'.$result.'" class = "folderLink" href="#">'.$result.'</a></img><br>';
            }

    }
?>
```

Above code displays all folder names inside templates as links using ajax.This is working fine.Now I want to go to the sub folders of each folder displayed. When I click on links none of them is working( no alert). Forget the ajax.Here is my jQuery which doesn't work.

```
$('.folderLink').on('click', function (e) { 
    alert('hello');
});
```

The whole thing is happening inside another jquery loaded div. I can't figure out the issue. Please help

Comment: USE `$(document).on("click",".folderLink",function(){ //do})`

Comment: Where is `.folderLink` appended to document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use delegate event binding. Direct event binding only worked if your `.folderLink` already in `DOM`. But in your case it get dynamically generated

```
$(document).on("click",".folderLink",function(){
 //do stuff
})
```

Comment: But this show popup three times. After closing popup it shows again.  Its fine added exit() to end.

Comment: for that you should write another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing .folderLink class css style in your DOM. Perhaps after an AJAX calling but no in initial state